# Is OpenCL a fast alternative for OpenGL and DirectX?

Tags: java, opengl, directx, opencl

I'm making a small Java game library and I wanted to make the drawing code for more Java oriented drawing rather then calling some C++ method to draw off of an API. Anyway I'm worried it may be slower then the other graphics APIs. So will this be a good option? One other question is that I can't find a useful OpenCL tutorial (I need to learn it first), does anyone know one?

Answer (score 5):

OpenCL is *not* a graphics API. It is not meant for rendering, and it generally doesn't do a very good job of it.

Furthermore, OpenCL is no "more Java oriented" than OpenGL. It's still a C-based API, so you will still be "calling some C++ method to draw off of an API".

Answer (score 2):

Well, [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is not a gpraphics API, but **heterogenous computation framework** that can use your videocard (or other specific devices) to make non-graphical calculations ([GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU)), similar to [DirectCompute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectCompute), [Compute shader in OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader), [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA), etc. 
It is no way object-oriented, because uses plain C interface. Although you can find bindings (for java: [JOCL](http://www.jocl.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

Also; you are aware that several good object orientated java graphics librarys available. Jmonkey engine for example.

As far as I'm aware if you want fast graphics that talk to the graphics card you have to go through openGL* (unlike openCL it is for graphics). All the java APIs do this behind the scenes, things like LWJGL do so with a very thin layer, basically just exposing the methods of OpenGL to Java: No object orientation at all. Others do so without the user ever realising its OpenGL, these tend to be "scene graph" type graphics engines and are fully object orientated.

If what you want is to create something that "feels like java" to the end user but uses OpenGL under the hood I'd start with something like LWJGL and then build on top of it. This is what JMonkey engine does.

All this is assuming you're working in 3D, if you're working in 2D then performance is unlikely to be an issue.

So to answer your question about if a full java graphics solution is a good idea:
It won't talk to the graphics card so you'll be relying on your CPU to do the work;
In 2D: this is probably fine, it'll be slower, but slower than very fast is still very fast.
In 3D: I doubt you'd be able to get it to work at real time speed for any realistic scene.

*or directX, but you'll have the same issues with that as well